# To use use statement in yii2: start a capital letter and small letter

Tags: yii2

why Yii2 can write with a capital letter:

```
use Yii;
```

as well as in small letters:

```
use yii;
```

then write for example:

```
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
     die('Okay! You are Guest!');
```

Both options work, but if you write:

```
use Yii\web\Controller;
```

you get the an error

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Class 'Yii\web\Controller' not found

Answer (score 0):

Because Classes are always written with capital letter.

When you use:

> use Yii;

You are 'using' a Class, and when you use:

> use Yii\web\Controller;

Can't work because this `Yii` isn't a class, is a route or `namespace`, the class is `Controller`

P.D: `use yii` namespace references to Yii class.

Comment: Well this is understandable
But to use a code such as the following code:
`Yii::$app->user->isGuest`
above, we write
`use Yii;`
but also works
`use yii;`
Normally documentation meet
`use Yii;`
For me, it means in the folder vendor/yiisoft/yii2/ will be loaded Yii.php
But also in the development of writing in small letters
`use yii;`
*What mechanism works in this case?*

Comment: Yii class have an autoload function, which use spl_autoload_register() function, and seems isn't case sensitive.